# MacOS nut client install for synology network ups

Tags: mac-osx, mac, ups, synology, nut

I have an APC UPS connected to my synology nas and I am trying to get my mac (10.13) to connect to the 'network ups' of synology.

So far I've been trying to follow this guide:

https://community.netgear.com/t5/New-to-ReadyNAS/NUT-on-OSX-10-6-Sharing-a-UPS-with-ReadyNAS-and-Computers/td-p/661293

And i've come so far as to have fink and findcommander installed.
However this is where I seem to lose all info on how to proceeed:

- I can't seem to find just "nut" on finkcommander, so what should i install ?
- If i go to the fink site and get an overview of the nut archives, which should I download and what do I do with them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems I was missing the point of fink a bit.

had to do:

```
sudo apt-get update
fink install nut
```

Updating the package lists with apt-get update also fixed finkcommander.

After installing nut (5mins) Setting up the config in /sw/etc/nut/ as found on the net
uncommenting a line:

```
MONITOR ups@<ip of synology> 1 monuser secret slave
```

After which sudo upsmon still gave an error of a missing library.
Error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded /sw/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

For this I installed openssl 1.0.2 using finkcommander
(fink installed a version too high)

Then running sudo upsmon no error was given.
Following https://community.netgear.com/t5/New-to-ReadyNAS/NUT-on-OSX-10-6-Sharing-a-UPS-with-ReadyNAS-and-Computers/td-p/661293
Showing 3 processes (one grep upsmon to be ignored):

```
ps aux | grep upsmon
```

And finally showing me the info of the ups:

```
sudo upsc UPS@<ip of nas>
```

All that's left is auto starting upsmon on boot by adding the following :
(credit https://superuser.com/questions/1228972/how-to-automatically-launch-nut-client-at-boot-on-macos/1358980#1358980).  Edited to add "s" to LaunchDaemons.

```
sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.networkupstools.upsmon.plist
```

and fill it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>org.networkupstools.upsmon</string>
   <key>OnDemand</key>
   <false/>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
           <string>/sw/sbin/upsmon</string>
           <string>-D</string>
   </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```